# Will Factory Reset remove root?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, root-access

I got my Samsung Galaxy Y rooted a month ago. Will a Factory Reset harm the phone? Will it still have root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Factory Reset will not remove root. However, you will lose all your data and all the apps that you installed. It will be good as new. Files in the external SD card will remain.

When the phone boots after a Factory Reset, you will be asked to log-in to your Google account again.

Comment: Thanks.

After factory reset i can't seem to find google play services on play store,which got uninstalled after reset,youtube too is not working i guess it needs play services

Tried downloading the apk but it would not install

Can you help

Comment: @Uzair In `Settings > Security`, make sure `Unknown sources` is checked so you can install the APK.